# How to make the epicurve (using EpiPy) shows up as a figure?

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I am following this [documentation](http://cmrivers.github.io/epipy/plots/2015/05/11/epicurves/),

```
import epipy
import pandas as pd

# mers_df is a pandas data frame that contains "dates" as a date column
curve, fig, ax = epipy.epicurve_plot(mers_df, date_col='dates', freq='month')
```

I run the script using sublime text, but no figure shows up as supposed to.

Comment: Have you tried ```fig.show()```?

Comment: Oh thanks, I tried fig.show() and plt.show(), both works.